# Select row id where SUM(field) reaches a specific point - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

With a 'standard' Orders table I am trying to find out how far back in time it was that a specific client purchased a certain numbers of items.

```
Order ID      Items      Client      Date
--------      -----      ------      ----

1             1          Fred        26/04/2012
2             3          John        25/04/2012
3             2          Fred        20/04/2012
4             5          Fred        18/04/2012
5             3          Fred        14/04/2012
6             4          Fred        10/04/2012
```

So I want to know the time frame covered by the last 10 items purchased by Fred, starting from now and working back.

In this instance I would be trying to identify that Order IDs 1, 3, 4 & 5 added together take me to (or just past) my target total of 10 items, so the date I am looking for is 14/04/2012.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_of_last(itemcount INT, custid VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
   DECLARE tally INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE ondate DATE;
   DECLARE curritems IN DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t.items, t.orderdate FROM yourtable t
      WHERE customer=custid ORDER BY orderdate DESC;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ondate = NULL;

   OPEN cur1;

   read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur1 INTO curritems, ondate;
       SET tally = tally+curritems;
       IF (tally>=itemcount) THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur1;

   RETURN ondate;
END;

SELECT time_of_last(10, 'Fred');
```

NB if you want to start gathering other information such as what orders are in the set, then Matt Fenwick's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *simple* way to do it given just what you have.

If you're tracking which items were ordered, you could join to the Items table so you have one row per item.  Then you can just select the top 10.

```
select *
from Orders o
join OrderItems oi on oi.orderId = o.orderId
join Items i on i.itemId = oi.itemId
where o.Client = 'Fred'
order by o.Date
limit 10;
```

Then syntax may vary depending on what DB you're using ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)).

Comment: OP is using MySQL as tagged in the question :)

Comment: Missed that tag.  Fixed the syntax so it's MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately the items table isn't available, I just have summary data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to calculate the running total of items purchased:

```
select 
  orders.*, 
  sum(
    select items 
    from orders as `inner` 
    where client = "Fred" and 
     `outer`.`date` <= `inner`.`date`
  ) as `Running total`
from orders as `outer`
where client = "Fred"
order by date desc;
```

Note the subquery in the select list that sums up the number of items that were bought on that date or later by Fred.

The output should be something like:

```
Order ID      Items      Client      Date         Running total
--------      -----      ------      ----         -------------

1             1          Fred        26/04/2012     1
3             2          Fred        20/04/2012     3
4             5          Fred        18/04/2012     8
5             3          Fred        14/04/2012     11
6             4          Fred        10/04/2012     15
```

Then from this result, you can easily select the appropriate row.

Comment: O(n^2) - not the most efficient solution.

Comment: True.  May or may not be a problem depending on the OP's data size and performance requirements.  Which weren't given.

Comment: This works but is a little slow with the data I have (1.5 million records). Would vote up if I could.